# Не удаётся yстановить пакет из NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

При попытке установки Json из NuGet в Visual Studio 2015 выдаёт следущее:

> Не удалось инициализировать узел PowerShell. Если для политики
>   выполнения PowerShell выбран режим AllSigned, откройте консоль
>   диспетчера пакетов, чтобы сначала инициализировать узел

OC Windows 10 Home 64 битная.

Comment: Ну, перезапустите Студию. Если не помогло, перезапустите ОС.

Comment: Перезапуск не  помогает.

Comment: VS запускается под администратором?

Comment: да, под админом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно запустить **PowerShell** (под правами администратора) и выполнить команду:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Будет предупреждение:

> Политика выполнения защищает компьютер от ненадежных сценариев. Изменение политики выполнения может поставить под угрозу безопасность системы, бла бла...

Подтверждаем выполнение и перезапускаем Visual Studio

Comment: В моем случае, это не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой.

В моем случае, когда я открыл npm console я увидел сообщение об ошибке инициализации npm. Там было, примерно, следующее:

> Nuget Package Manager requires PowerShell 2.0 to be installed. Please
>   follow the link to get PowerShell 2.0.

Ссылка ведет на сайт microsoft, где можно скачать PowerShell для версий Windows до 7.

В Windows 8-10 **PowerShell 2.0** — это компонент системы, находится он в **Windows Features**.

После того, как я включил PS 2.0 и перезагрузил студию, проблема решилась.

Answer (score 0):

Та же ошибка появлялась при создании веб-приложений Visual Studio 2017 (C#) на Windows 10.
Перезагрузки не помогли.
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned - не помогло.
Обновил (установил) до последней версии Microsoft SQL Server с официального сайта и всё заработало.

Answer (score -1):

Там что-то связано с разрядностью PowerShell (64bit) и VS (32bit). Получается (насколько я понял), NuGet использует 32-разрядную консоль PowerShell, а нам надо использовать 64-разрядную (по системе). Следовательно надо настроить политику безопасности (ну или что-то такое) в PowerShell и подключить 64-битную как 32-битную.

Что надо сделать (кстати, перезагрузка системы тоже помогает):

1. Открыть *Windows PowerShell*, запустить под администратором.
2. В PowerShell консоли запустите следующий скрипт:

   ```
   start-job { Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned } -RunAs32 | wait-job | Receive-Job
   ```
3. Перезапустите Visual Studio.

Comment: Не обязательно выяснять, какую он использует консоль. Вы можете изменить ExecutionPolicy для обоих разрядностей PS.

Answer (score -2):

Нужно, чтобы проект лежал на том же диске, что и студия. Не знаю, как это связано, но мне помогло.